# how to remove the following lint warning in C?

Tags: c, loops, lint

I have the following code:

```
#define NUM_DAYS 65
#define NUM_PERSON 33

int num = 0;

if(NUM_DAYS % NUM_PERSON)
{
    num = NUM_DAYS / NUM_PERSON;
}
else 
{
    uum = NUM_DAY / NUM_PERSON + 1;
}

num = num - 1;

while(num > 0)
{
    //do something here
}
```

but I got the following lint warning:

```
Warning 681: Loop is not entered
```

what is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: The problem is that you first set `num` to `65/33`, which is `1`, then subtract one, so `num` is `0` when the loop condition is checked. Lint says that might not be what you intended, so let's warn about it.

Comment: Moral of the story: Beware the truncation of integer division.

Comment: `uum =` in the else clause looks like a typo

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As your code is written, the loop will not be entered. `NUM_DAYS % NUM_PERSON` will evaluate to `true`, so `num` will equal `NUM_DAYS / NUM_PERSON`. Since we are dealing with ints, `65 / 33` is equal to `1`. `1 -1` is `0`, so the while condition will fail.

If your code is written as intended (as in, those constants are the values you are expecting to always use), just remove the while loop. It will never be used. If, however, `NUM_DAYS` or `NUM_PERSON` may later contain other values, you probably have nothing to worry about. If those specific values aren't important, try setting them to values such that the division will evaluate to something greater than `1`.

Comment: Someone had commented that I didn't really answer the question of how to fix it. They were right, so I added additional explanation.

Comment: "*For now, try setting them to values such that the division will evaluate to something greater than 1*" - are you suggesting to intentionally break the program logic to satisfy lint?!

Comment: @icepack Only if the values of those constants don't matter! I prefaced that with a statement of what to do if the code is indeed written as intended, i.e. those constants are exactly what the OP wants for now and forever.

Comment: if these constants don't matter they should be removed, not altered to yield result that shuts lint up.

Comment: @icepack I figured it was possible that this code was merely preliminary and that the intention was for these values to be able to change at runtime in the future. If that were to be the case, then it doesn't make a great difference what they are set to now.

Comment: I changed my explanation slightly to make it clear that values should only be fiddled with if it doesn't matter what they are.

Answer (score 6):

```
#define NUM_DAYS 65
#define NUM_PERSON 33

int num = 0;

if(NUM_DAYS % NUM_PERSON) // we go here, since (NUM_DAYS % NUM_PERSON) > 0
{
    num = NUM_DAYS / NUM_PERSON; // so num = 1 now
}
else 
{
    uum = NUM_DAY / NUM_PERSON + 1;
}

num = num - 1; // num = 0 now

while(num > 0) // num = 0 ! So we don't go in this loop
{
    //do something here
}
```

That's why you get this warning. The compiler has determined that your loop is useless (with your current `#define` value).

Answer (score 4):

Because both expression's value in if-else known at compilation time as follows :

In `if (num == 0)` in else `num` == `1`, So before while loop `num` value is either `0` (from else), or `-1` (from if) that is not greater than `0` that means `while` -condition is always false known at compilation time. This means while never executes known at compilation time.

Why static inputs in your code? you have given value at compilation time, ask it from user will be correct.

Remove macros and like below:

```
int num_days, number_persons;
scanf("%d", &num_days);
scanf("%d", &number_persons);
```

This will work, note statically assigning these 65, 33 values is problem!

Answer (score 0):

@patrickvacek is right.  I will extend his explanation.

In integer arithmetic, 65 divided by 33 is almost 2 but not quite.  The quotient is 1 with a remainder of 32.  C++ lets you access either the quotient or the remainder, as you prefer.  For the quotient, `65 / 33 == 1`.  For the remainder, `65 % 33 == 32`.  Your code does not ask for the remainder, but only for the quotient.  Thus, `if (NUM_DAYS % NUM_PERSON)` literally means `if (1)`, which in turn means `if (true)`.  Thus, the `else` branch of your `if` statement is never reached.

You can follow the rest.  Moreover, because the logic is comparatively simple (and for other reasons having to do with the preprocessor and compile-time evaluation, which we will not detail here), the *compiler* can follow the rest.  Thus the warning.

Answer (score -1):

Your compiler computes the value of `num` already since its possible value could be `65 / 33 or 34` which is demoted to `0` since it is an `int` type or `num = num - 1` which is `-1`, and substitute the value in `while ((0 or -1) > 0)`. That is why compiler warns you about it.